# SQL Update query when there is an existing date in table by importing .csv files using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a code that will get to create and insert .csv files to MySQL. Now what I want to get is how to Update my data if there is already an existing date in my table by importing a .csv file.

I tried to do it with a simple Update Query and its working fine... but the tricky part is to get the date from .csv file and compare it to the date that is in MySQL. Can you give me any hints on how to this?

Here's my code:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\csvfiles\ADJTIME.csv';
$table = 'adjtime';


    ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
$handle = fopen($file,'r');
// first row, structure
 if ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) === FALSE ) {
//echo "Cannot read from csv $file";die();
}
$fields = array();
$field_count = 0;
for($i=0;$i<count($data); $i++) {
$f = strtolower(trim($data[$i]));
if ($f) {
// normalize the field name, strip to 20 chars if too long
$f = substr(preg_replace ('/[^0-9a-z]/', '_', $f), 0, 100);
$field_count++;


 if($f == 'date'){
     $fields[] = '`'.$f.'` DATE()';
} else {
$fields[] = '`'.$f.'` VARCHAR(500)';

}
}
} 


$sqlgetdate = ("SELECT DATE from $table where DATE = '5/3/2017' ");

echo $sqlgetdate;
$sqlupdate = ("UPDATE $table SET Fieldname = 'John' where DATE = '5/3/2017' ");
echo $sqlupdate;
```

Comment: You need to maintain a format for the csv file. Ex: 1st Column is A.ID and 2nd is DATE.

Then loop through the result that you got by fgetcsv and run a query to check is that date is in your table or not. If available then do something, if not then do something

Comment: is the date column in your table is unique key?

Comment: @DileepKumar yep its a unique key

Comment: Ok, then use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement as i already answered.

Answer (score 1):

mysql accepts date format in `'yyyy-mm-dd'`
so your query should be `$sqlgetdate = ("SELECT DATE from $table where DATE = '2017-03-05' ");` and `$sqlupdate = ("UPDATE $table SET Fieldname = 'John' where DATE = '2017-03-05' ");`

Comment: I've changed but it didnt answer my current question :( 
I was wondering if there is a code where you can read the date of the .csv file and compare it to MySQL table date.

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique key on date column and use the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement.

Documentation can be found [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)